# How can I hide Accordion Specific Content in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, accordion

In this example, I want to show and hide feature for the content of accordion.
This is my source code.

```
state = {
    check: true,
};

 renderContent = (order, _, isActive) => {
    //Accordion Content   
    return (
         <View style={styles.child}>
                   <View>
                     <Text>Hello World</Text>
                   </View>

                   <View>
                     <Text>Goodbye</Text>
                   </View>
                }
         </View>
        )
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.scrollMain}>
                <CheckBox
                    value = { this.state.check}
                    onValueChange={(newValue) => this.setState({check:newValue})}/> // this is my checkbox
                <Accordion
                    .....
                    renderContent={this.renderContent}
                    }/> 
            }
        </View>
    );
```

What I want to do is if I click to checkbox, it should hide this content below

```
                `<View>
                  <Text>Goodbye</Text>
                </View>`
```

When I uncheck checkbox it should go back. Give me please idea how I can do it?

Comment: What it's mean `hide this content below`? whats content?

Comment: `<View>
                  <Text>Goodbye</Text>
                </View>`
This I mean

Answer (score 1):

Hi you almost have it done, you just have to think the `this.state.check` condition is the one that will handle the content so you have several options to achieve this:

- You can create another component to handle this logic.
- Instead use a **JSX** block to handle this logic.
- Or you can use **css** with a class or something similar to just hide the content but the elements will always exist.

I think that this decision invovles your use case but a straightforward way to do it is encapsulating the  logic in a **JSX** block

```
renderContent = (order, _, isActive) => {
    //Accordion Content   
    return (
         <View style={styles.child}>
                   <View>
                     <Text>Hello World</Text>
                   </View>

                   {
                    !this.state.check?
                     <View>
                      <Text>Goodbye</Text>
                     </View> 
                    : null
                   }
                }
         </View>
        )
}
```

Comment: how checkbox identifies it ? The task is not to just hide, but by clicking to checkbox it should hide it, by unchecking checkbox it should do the vice verse

Comment: Hey @Jasur, tanking this in count we can tell that the `state` value that is controlling the Component is the `this,state.check` so you just have to change the `isActive` to `this.state.cehck`

Answer (score 1):

Try this condition, if you want other behaviors just tell me

```
     renderContent = (order, _, isActive) => {
    //Accordion Content   
    return (
         <View style={styles.child}>
                   <View>
                     <Text>Hello World</Text>
                   </View>

                {!this.state.check &&
                   <View>
                     <Text>Goodbye</Text>
                   </View>}
                }
         </View>
        )
}
```